# how to activate function only if clicks first column with jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatable

How to activate this code only if click on the first column of the line?
`tr>td:first:`  does not work

```
$('#tbldata tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    } else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your selector to match the `first child` (td) of the table row and then use `$(this).parent()` to set the class of the row:

```
$('#tbldata tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {
if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('selected') ) {
} else {
    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tbldata tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:first-child', function (e) {
    if ( ! $(this).parent().hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why the code works.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25723575)